# AOSP Build Error - make fails

Tags: android, go, makefile, build, android-source

When I try to run `mm`, `make` or even `make clobber` I get the error below. I have followed the instructions from Google and have searched for the issue on the Internet. I haven't found anything that helps solve my problem. Can anybody advise as to what might be the problem here?

The source was downloaded 23/11/2016. I'm running Ubtuntu 14.04.5. I've install OpenJDK 8. I've downloaded the Nexus 6P (angler) binaries for Android (3429405) and run them from the root directory. I have make 3.81. When I run '`make clobber`' as advised [here](https://source.android.com/source/building.html), it produces the error below. I've narrowed the problem down to a go file (`module.go`) but I can't see how to fix it.

```
x@x-VirtualBox:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ make clobber
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-31-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NYC
OUT_DIR=out
AUX_OS_VARIANT_LIST=
============================================
ninja: no work to do.
[1/27] compile out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-android/pkg/android/soong/android.a
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-android/pkg/android/soong/android.a 
GOROOT='./prebuilts/go/linux-x86' ./prebuilts/go/linux-x86/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile -o out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-android/pkg/android/soong/android.a -p android/soong/android -complete -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-parser/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-deptools/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-pathtools/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-proptools/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-bootstrap-bpdoc/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-bootstrap/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/soong/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-env/pkg -pack build/soong/android/androidmk.go build/soong/android/arch.go build/soong/android/config.go build/soong/android/defaults.go build/soong/android/defs.go build/soong/android/expand.go build/soong/android/hooks.go build/soong/android/makevars.go build/soong/android/module.go build/soong/android/mutator.go build/soong/android/onceper.go build/soong/android/package_ctx.go build/soong/android/paths.go build/soong/android/prebuilt.go build/soong/android/register.go build/soong/android/util.go build/soong/android/variable.go build/soong/android/env.go
build/soong/android/module.go:526: unknown blueprint.BuildParams field 'Deps' in struct literal
[2/27] compile out/soong/.bootstrap/so...g-android/test/android/soong/android.a
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-android/test/android/soong/android.a 
GOROOT='./prebuilts/go/linux-x86' ./prebuilts/go/linux-x86/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile -o out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-android/test/android/soong/android.a -p android/soong/android -complete -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-parser/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-deptools/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-pathtools/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-proptools/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-bootstrap-bpdoc/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/blueprint-bootstrap/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/soong/pkg -I out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-env/pkg -pack build/soong/android/androidmk.go build/soong/android/arch.go build/soong/android/config.go build/soong/android/defaults.go build/soong/android/defs.go build/soong/android/expand.go build/soong/android/hooks.go build/soong/android/makevars.go build/soong/android/module.go build/soong/android/mutator.go build/soong/android/onceper.go build/soong/android/package_ctx.go build/soong/android/paths.go build/soong/android/prebuilt.go build/soong/android/register.go build/soong/android/util.go build/soong/android/variable.go build/soong/android/env.go build/soong/android/expand_test.go build/soong/android/paths_test.go build/soong/android/prebuilt_test.go
build/soong/android/module.go:526: unknown blueprint.BuildParams field 'Deps' in struct literal
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [run_soong] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####
```

Comment: I see references to `blueprint` here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10509843. I wonder if blueprint (which generates rules used by ninja) needs to be installed first.

Comment: @scorpiodawg Thanks for the reply. build/blueprint seems to be present with the same files as is on the blueprint github page. It still has the above error though. Do you have any other ideas? :-)

Answer (score 0):

> unknown blueprint.BuildParams field `Deps` in struct literal

The `Deps` and `Depfile` fields has been added into `BuildParams` struct (`ninja_defs.go` file) on 22th Nov 2016 as per [`aa873e1` commit (PR: #135)](https://github.com/google/blueprint/pull/135/files), so I believe your [Blueprint sources](https://github.com/google/blueprint) are out-of-date. Try updating it, verify the content of `ninja_defs.go` file and re-try again.